# JavaScript Scope: Global Variable Confusion

Tags: javascript, scope

I am having trouble understanding why the following code prints 1 and not 10. I thought that `console.log` would print 10 because if a variable is not declared within a function it is part of the global scope.

If I remove the line, `function a(){}`, the `console.log` statement prints 10. Can someone please explain why the presence of this line affects the value of `a`.

Additionally, if this question can be refined I would appreciate any suggestions

```js
function b() { 
    a = 10; 
    return;
    function a(){}
} 
var a = 1; 
b(); 

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `console.log(a);` to your function and you will realize that 'a'  is a function that has local scope, which means, it inside function b() and can't really be called from outside. Hence, the value of a remains as 1, as nothing really affects it.

```js
function b() { 
    console.log(a);
    a = 10; 
    return;
    function a(){}
} 
var a = 1; 
b(); 

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations create local variables, and all declared variables are *hoisted* to the top of their containing function scope. Thus, you have something equivalent to:

```
function b() { 
    function a(){}
    a = 10; 
    return;
}
```

which is in turn roughly equivalent to

```
function b() { 
    var a = function(){}
    a = 10; 
    return;
}
```

As you can see in this form, it's clear that `a` is a local variable, so `a = 10` assigns a value to the local `a`, not the global `a`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Because both function declarations and variables are treated similarly under the hood.

When a function is called, its contents are first parsed to configure the stack frame ready for its execution.

As part of this process, function declarations and variables are inserted as identifier/value pairs into the same data structure (Environment Record inside the Lexical Environment) inside the stack frame (Execution Context) created when a function is called.

So by declaring a function `a` inside `b`, you create an identifier named "a" in the Environment Record created for the call to `b`, shadowing `a` in the outer context.

So `a` in the outer context remains `1`.

Comment: It appears someone just came through and downvoted the question and all answers, which, to answer your question, sounds indicative of a "this question is not worth answering" mindset. Not, of course, a good reason to downvote an answer, especially for a question about (somewhat) surprising, reproducible behavior that's clearly on-topic